# Usage of Drawable.ConstantState

Tags: android, performance, android-drawable

I came across a lib where mDrawable.getConstantState().newDrawable(mResources) is used. Now, since it seems that the system already does this kind of caching automatically, I am wondering, is there any reason at all to use this method?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, and I am going to answer my own question, just in case it helps someone.

When you obtain a drawable using a resource id, the system will automatically do the caching for you. On the other hand, when you get your drawable object in another way (ex. Drawable.createFromStream(InputStream)), you can use the above method to gain the same caching advantages.

Note, however, that it won't work on your custom drawables, unless you override getConstantState() and return a correct implementation of the ConstantState abstract class.